# Increment android database version via onclick. (SQLiteOpenHelper)

Tags: android

Is it possible (simple) to get the current database version number, increment it, and pass it to SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor from within an activity rather then hard coding the version number like so?

Activity (called from onclick):

```
public void updatedb(){
    //pseudo-code next 2 comments
    //int incVersion = getCurrentDBVersion();<==question here
    //incVersion = incVersion + 1;
    DatabaseHandler dbincrement = new DatabaseHandler(this, incVersion);
}
```

SQLiteOpenHelper Extension:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context, int incVersion) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, incVersion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use something like this to get the [database version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion%28%29):

```
DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dh.getWriteableDatabase();
int version = db.getVersion();
DatabaseHandler dhInc = new DatabaseHandler(this, version++);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the current db version number unless you first open the database.  So if your intention was to get the installed database version, increment it, and *then* call the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor with the new version than I don't believe what Sam proposed will satisfy your request.

Here's why:

1) the first line in a DatabaseHandler constructor must invoke the SQLiteOpenHelper (super) constructor, providing your database version.
2) invoking getWriteableDatabase automatically causes the invocation of the onOpen and/or onUpgrade/onDowngrade methods in your DatabaseHandler.  Which onXXXX method is called depends on SQLiteOpenHelper's comparison of the installed database version to the version you provided in your constructor initialization above.

I don't know an easy way to find out the installed database version without providing one first.